# Left join on a table variable fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join

See below I do not get a row for each stats
This left join acts like an inner join
I get 6 rows and expect 9
I want 3 rows for each name (null data if there is no match)
How to fix this?

```
declare @table table (name varchar(10), status int, data int);
insert into @table values 
  ('a', 1, 2)
, ('a', 2, 5)
, ('a', 3, 7)
, ('b', 1, 5) 
, ('b', 2, 6)
, ('c', 1, 3) 

select stats.status as statusStats
     , t.status as statusData, t.name, t.data
from (values (1),(2),(3)) as stats(status)
left join @table t 
  on t.status = stats.status
```

Desired output

```
  ('a', 1, 2)
, ('a', 2, 5)
, ('a', 3, 7)
, ('b', 1, 5) 
, ('b', 2, 6)
, ('b', 3, null)
, ('c', 1, 3) 
, ('c', 2, null)
, ('c', 3, null)
```

Comment: What are the 9 rows you would be expecting? For the SQL you've provided, 6 is correct.

Comment: @Larnu May I am not understanding this correctly.  I will correct the problem statement or delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably expecting a cartesian product between `name` and `status` values. Well, bad luck - SQL can't "guess" this, you have to introduce the multiplication manually:

```
select stats.status as statusStats, t.status as statusData, t.name, t.data
from (values (1),(2),(3)) stats(status)
  cross join (values ('a'),('b'),('c')) names(name)
left join @table t 
  on t.status = stats.status
  and t.name = names.name;
```

Comment: Hard coding a, b, c is not possible but I think you have addressed the problem

Comment: Of course, this is just for illustrational purposes. Normally, you would have a lookup with distinct values; in the worst case, something like `select distinct name from @table` would suffice.